# Can you do absolute positioning in a flex 4 application?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, position, absolute

With flex 4 you can't seem to just do layout="absolute" any more. Is there a way to get the application layout set as absolute in flex 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the BasicLayout

```
<s:layout>
    <s:BasicLayout />
</s:layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi
Under the application tag

```
</s:BorderContainer>
```

enjoy